# Is any whatsapp API available to broadcast message & sent to my contacts in whatsapp?

Tags: python, rest, web-services, asp.net-web-api, whatsapp

Is any whatsapp API or 3rd party API available to broadcast my message (like Text, Files, Etc..) & sent to my contacts or to whatsapp.

Paid / Free API will work for me.

Any API code base will be good for me like Python, C#, VB.net, java, php, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WhatsApp doesn´t have a public API so far. There is just one company from the Netherlands that is currently testing it. Anyway, there are some third-party APIs as well, e. g. WhatsATool, WhatsBroadcast, etc. but they are kind of expensive. Maybe WhatsMate could be an interesting solution for you, can check it here https://www.whatsmate.net/
I´ve checked waboxapp as well, but it didn´t work, but maybe you can give a try too. I think, you know that there are some things to consider, WhatsApp doesn´t make jokes about Spam-protection ;)
Hope it helps,
KR,
J

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your Response @Jan As I've also tried some of the solution by researching about & Verified it, but no Result & yes paid API are really expensive & don't know if they work or not. Also Tried your some API you suggested. Thanks !